# javascript properties .net properties

Tags: javascript, .net, properties

Could you please compare the properties

I want to disable a text box 'txtName'. There are two ways

1. Use javascript, `txtName.disabled = true`
2. Use ASP.NET , `<.. Enabled="false" ..>`

Which method is better and Why?

Comment: `txtName.disabled('disabled')` is bad. the proper syntax is `txtName.disabled = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Enabled="false"` results in `disabled="disabled"` in the generated HTML code. In this case that's clearly the better way as it doesn't require the user to have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable a button, the server side method would require a round trip (postback of the page, event handlers run, response returned).

The client side method (javascript) does not require this.

However, if javascript is disables, the client side method will not work.

In either case, the end result is the same (the `disabled` attribute is set).

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference.

Comment: Of course there is. One is client side code, the other is server side. The execution of them is totally different, even if the end result isn't.